# Power Calculation for Annotating Data

Tags: chi-squared-test, statistical-power, multinomial-distribution

I need a power calculation for annotating data. We draw from a database of customer complaints with two separate labels. One for the product and then another for the customer's complaint. We change the charateristics of the employee population as driven by the business needs. As such we have no prior information about this distribution or its variance as each annotation is unique. We need to be able to justify why we choose our sample sizes, which are manually labeled (and thus expensive to create).

Here is a sample of what the data will look like

| Complaint ID | Product label | Complaint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Complaint ID 1 | Medicine | Too Expensive |
| Complaint ID 2 | Food | Bad Quality |
| Complaint ID 3 | Cosmetics | Bad Quality |
| Complaint ID 4 | Food | Too Expensive |

It seems like this could be modeled as a big multinomial distribution and then use that for the power calculation. Just take every Product and Complaint possible combination and use that to back out the power, prior to actually labelling the data.

Another alternative would be to use a Chi-Square Calculation. Intuitively, I think this might actually be the same, but am I not sure.

I am aware it might come back with sample sizes that are unrealistic for high confidence. I also know we should first prioritize meaningful categories. This is actually what I am trying to calculate to show stakeholders.

Edit: I am looking at calculating the sample size to use for 95% confidence interval with a marign of +/-.05. My issue is I am not sure what probability distribution to use.

Comment: What are you testing? What's your null hypothesis?

Comment: Hey, I am trying to do a power calculation to justify sample size. I think my NULL hypothesis would be based off of maximizing assumed variance. Not unlike assuming p=50% in this link https://www.calculator.net/sample-size-calculator.html

Comment: Power analysis is for a significance test, which tests a null hypothesis. Forget about power for a moment, say you have your data. What's the null hypothesis? Is it that all product labels have the same proportion of complaints of each type?

Comment: Or maybe you're not actually interested in power and the null hypothesis, but in confidence intervals?

Comment: Yes! I am interested in the sample size required to get a specific confidence interval! All calculators online use a Wald Test with a single binary porportion. I am looking to generalize that to include two categorical question (I think results in 2 multinomial distributions combining into 1 mutlinomial distributions).